# how to add coustomized side frame to doxygen html

Tags: html, doxygen

I am using doxygen to generate an API document for my project  written in pure C. I want to have a left side frame in the index.html generated by doxygen. So I enabled the option "GENERATE_TREEVIEW" in Doxyfile, but I am not satisfied with its layout.

I want a brief tree layout, not like this :

```
Files

    File List

    File Members

         All

         Functions
```

I have only one file to export, so I don't need "File List".

I have only functions to export(no variables, class etc.), so I don't need "File members".

And, the most reason I want to customize is that I want to classify my API into several different sub-class. Just like this:

```
Cursor Operation
    vi_h()
    vi_j()
    vi_k()
    vi_l()
Text Edit
    vi_dw()
    vi_dd()
Text Search
    vi_f()
    vi_F()
```

But doxygen seems doesn't provide a way to customize the side frame.
I have thought about another way: give up side frame, and use an category page, which can be accomplished using \section and @ref. But this is not good for readers, because every time they click, they have to switch to another web-brower tab, slow and inconvenient.